# how to get Parameters from a json file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am working in Python with a JSON file. When I print `date` it comes out like this :

```
print (date['slot'])
[{'slot': 1, 'type': {'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/11/', 'name': 
'water'}}]
```

But I just want to get `'water'`. I have been using different methods and it did not work. Can someone please help me to get just `'water'` from the code?

Comment: `date['slot'][0]["type"]['name']` ?

Comment: `for  d in data['slot']: print d['type']['name']` is this what you're looking for?

Comment: hi Madhan Varadhodiyil, it still keep saying this:  for d in c ['slot']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: hi  Madhan Varadhodiyil  , im just wanna get name : water

Answer (score 0):

```
print (date['slot'][0]['type']['name'])
```

OR

```
print (date['slot'][0]['type']['name'] if date['slot'] else None)
```

OR More generic

```
for sd in date['slot']:
    print (sd['type']['name'])
```

Comment: hi Gaurav Jain , it say : for sd in c ['slot']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: with the second option say : print (c['slot'][0]['type']['name'] if c['slot'] else None)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>>>

Comment: c is the variable's name i change it from date to c

Comment: try `c[0]['type']['name']`